# MS SQL Server, arrays, looping, and inserting qualified data into a table

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql

I've searched around for answer and I'm not sure how best to frame the question since I'm rather new to SQL Server.

Here's what I got going on: I get a weekly report detailing the products that have been sold and the quantity of each. This data needs to go into a yearly totals table. In this table the first column is the product_id and the next 52 columns are week numbers, 1-52.

There's a JOIN that runs on the product_id of both the weekly and yearly tables. That finds the proper row and column to put the weekly quantity data for that product.

Here's where I'm not sure what to do. In 2019 there are no product_id in that column. So there's nothing to JOIN on. Those product_id need to be added weekly if they aren't there. I need to take the weekly report of product_id and quantity and check each product_id to see if it's in the yearly table. If not I need to add it.

If I had it my way I'd create an array of the product_id numbers from the weekly data and loop through each one creating a new record in the yearly table for any product_id that is not already there. I don't know how best to do that in SSMS.

I've searched around and have found different strategies for this. Nothing strikes me as being a perfect solution. There's creating a @temp table variable, a UNION using exclude to get just those that aren't in the table, and a WHILE loop. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Either build a Calendar table which includes all dates at the level of granularity desired or use a recursive CTE and build it at run time. You'd start wtih this table and cross join it to your years so that  52 weeks per year. and then left join this to your source data.  This way ever year will always have 52 weeks

Comment: Loading the weekly data into a temporary table or table variable will let you approach the problem in a set-based way. You can add the "missing" products to the yearly table in a variety of ways before updating the sales data: `insert into Yearly ... where not exists ( ... );`, `merge`, ... . Once all of the products are in you can perform the `update`. Aside: Life might be easier with a table that has `ProductId`, `YearNo`, `WeekNo` and `SalesQuantity` rather than a column per week. Where do you put the 53rd week now? ([ISO Weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year).)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm new to MSSS and the suggestions are beyond my experience but not beyond my understanding.

This is part of a part production forcasting system. The data comes from 3 different sales sources. This particular source only provides weekly data. So there never is a 53rd week. So it's a 364 day year. Not sure how to work with that but right now it's not the problem I need to solve.

I picked this up from a previous developer. I assumed they were heading in the right direction but I fear not. I think the set theory approach is what I'll start with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a MERGE to solve this. I create a table WeeklyParts to dump the weekly data into. Then I do a MERGE with the yearly table inserting only those where the is no match. Works well.

```
-- Merge the PartNo's so that only unique ones are added to the yearly table
MERGE INTO dbo.WeeklySales2018
USING dbo.WeeklyParts
ON (dbo.WeeklySales2018.PartNo = dbo.WeeklyParts.PartNo)

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (PartNo) VALUES (dbo.WeeklyParts.PartNo);
```